# How can I access environment variables set by wfastcgi from a separate secrets config file

Tags: python, iis, flask, web-config, fastcgi

I have followed this guide to serve a Flask app from IIS:

https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8

My source code at present is as follows:

MyApp.py:

```
from flask import Flask
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():

    return "PYTHONPATH: {0}".format(os.getenv('PYTHONPATH'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings file='C:\app_secrets\secrets.config' >
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="MyApp.app" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I'm following the advice of a number of places on the internet to populate secrets by having a separate appSettings file outside of the source code and referencing it in the web.config, so 'C:\app_secrets\secrets.config' looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SECRETTHING" value="THING" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

What I'm finding is that though the web.config `<add key=...` bits work as I expect and I can access them in MyApp.py using `os.getenv()` the same is not true of the keys added in secrets.config; changing the line `return "PYTHONPATH: {0}".format(os.getenv('PYTHONPATH'))` to `return "PYTHONPATH: {0}".format(os.getenv('SECRETTHING'))` returns "None" rather than "THING".

Why can't I access those envars?

Comment: Any resolution on this? I literally hardcoded my wsgi file..

Comment: @wdfc There was! I definitely got that system working...but I can't for the life of me remember how and I no longer work at the company this was for so I can't check for you. Sorry...

Comment: I ended up fixing it actually by adding the env variables in the FastCGI Handler on IIS. It was super easy haha!